# Executing a python script from SQL Server Agent

Tags: python-2.7

Python script not running from SQL Server Agent

the python script makes use of the requests library (installed)
when i run from CMD :
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\main.py"
this works fine.
when i run it from SQL agent as an Operating System (CmdExec) all i get is "System cannot find the file specified"
i have set the enviorment paths.
I have created a proxy account (sys admin)
i have copied the requests library so its in the same folder as Python.

nothing is working
37 failed attempts today , and counting !
can anyone assist>

python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\main.py"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i managed to get it working.
manually moved some libraries around in python.